# Svelte script bug: Switch element click event does not fire

Tags: javascript, svelte

I am new to Svelte and there are things I suppose should be easy to do and yet they give me trouble. In a small Svelte app I have this HTML:

```
<div class="mt-5 mb-6">
   <Switch on:click={toggle} /> <span>{stat}</span>
</div>
```

I need to display "On" or "Off" in the span element, depending on the "state" of the switch. For this purpose, I have:

```
import Switch from './Switch.svelte';
let stat = 'off';
let status = false;

function toggle () {
 status = !status;
     stat = status ? "on" : "off";
}
```

See REPL **[here](https://svelte.dev/repl/141afebd8ca347a5ba38e5055aa817fb?version=3.23.2)**.

For a reason I can not understand, even though there's no error in the console, the span always shows "Off". Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making it too complicated. You can easily bind to the checked value of the underlying component:

```
<script>
    import Switch from './Switch.svelte';
    let status;
    
</script>

<div>
    <Switch bind:checked={status} /> <span>{status ? "on" : "off"}</span>
</div>
```

Before, you tried to listen to an *click* event, which your `Switch` component does not have, that is why it did not work. But as it is a checkbox, it has the checked property. Find more info [here](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/component-bindings).

Comment: I want to keep my HTML as clean as possible. What shall I replace the click event with?

Comment: You can replace it with the `bind:checked={status}`. Check it in this REPL: https://svelte.dev/repl/dae8a556dac44ac1b48a949dd2ae61f2?version=3.23.2

Comment: Thanks! Have a look at **[this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62551145/4512005)** too.

Comment: Hey, the link goes to this page. I also see from the other answer, that I did not understand your second question about the tidy html. I would have done it the same way as @RazvanZamfir

Answer (score 2):

Another version, with no logic in the HTML (and all of it inside the `<script>` tag):

```
<script>
    import Switch from '../ui/Switch.svelte';
    let stat = 'off';
    let status = false;
    $:stat = status ? "On" : "Off"; 
</script>

<div>
    <Switch bind:checked={status} /> <span>{stat}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another version, using the event dispatcher from the child component to emit the click event to the parent:

```
//Switch.svelte
<script>
    import { createEventDispatcher } from 'svelte';

    const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();
</script>

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" on:click="{() => dispatch('toggle')}"/>
  <span class="slider" />
</label>
```

...

```
//App.svelte
<script>
    import Switch from './Switch.svelte';
    let stat = 'off';
    let status = false;
    
    function toggle () {
     status = !status;
         stat = status ? "on" : "off";
  }
</script>

<div class="mt-5 mb-6">
    <Switch on:toggle={toggle} /> <span>{stat}</span>
</div>
```